# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, power-series

> For what complex values of $z$ is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}$$ convergent?

I would like to write the sum as a power series, because with a power series we can determine the radius of convergence. But in this case it seems untidy. We have $\dfrac{1}{1+z^{2n}}=1-z^{2n}+z^{4n}-\cdots$, so that the original sum is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kz^{n+2nk}$$ and I don't think that's very useful...

Comment: Well, it's not even defined, much less convergent, for some $z$. :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for your comment. What is not defined for some $z$?

Comment: $z^{2n}+1=0$ is possible.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Good point! So we must rule out the case $z=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}+\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}+\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a good time for the ratio test:

Defining $a_n=\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| &=
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{z^{n+1}}{1+z^{2(n+1)}} \frac{1+z^{2n}}{z^n}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} z\frac{1+z^{2n}}{1+z^{2(n+1)}}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{z+z^{2n+1}}{1+z^{2(n+1)}}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{z^{-2n-1}+z^{-1}}{z^{-2n-2}+1}
\end{align}
$$
When $|z|\neq 1$, the above approaches zero, implying convergence. Otherwise, the test is inconclusive.

In fact, we can conclude that the terms of the sum do not converge to zero when $|z|=1$ since by the triangle inequality, we have
$$
\begin{align}
|a_n| &= \left| \frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}\right|\\
&=\frac{|z|^n}{|1+z^{2n}|}\\
&\geq \frac{|z|^n}{|1|+|z|^{2n}} 
= \frac{1^n}{1+1^{2n}}=\frac12
\end{align}
$$
Which means that the sum must diverge for all such values.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** If $|z|\lt 1$, it should be a straightforward comparison, after a while the norm of the $n$-th term is $\lt \frac{1}{2}|z|^n$.

If $|z|=1$, the terms do not approach $0$, so we cannot have convergence.

And if $|z|\gt 1$ it should be a straightforward comparison: divide top and bottom by $z^n$.

The conclusion will be that we have convergence if $|z|\ne 1$.

Comment: No on terms, but yes on norms of terms. That is ultimately what the Ratio and Root tests are, comparison of norms with a geometric series.

Comment: If $|z| < 1$, I think for large $n$ we cannot have $< \dfrac{1}{2} |z|^n$, since the norm of the denominator $|1 + z^{2n}|$ is close to 1, therefore it should be something like the norm $< 2|z|^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: When $|z|<1$ we have $$\left|\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}\right| \le \frac{|z|^n}{1-|z|^{2}},$$
when $|z|>1$ we have
$$\left|\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}\right| \sim {|z|^{-n}}$$
and when $|z|=1$ we have
$$\left|\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}\right| \not\to 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $|z|<1$ then
$$\left|\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}\right|\leq \frac{|z|^n}{1-|z|^{2n}}\sim_\infty |z|^n$$
and the geometric series $\sum_n |z|^n$ is convergent so the given series is absolutely convergent.

If $|z|>1$ then
$$\left|\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}\right|\leq \frac{|z|^n}{|z|^{2n}-1}\sim_\infty |z|^{-n}$$
and the geometric series $\sum_n |z|^{-n}$ is convergent so the given series is absolutely convergent.

If $|z|=1$ then the series is divergent since the general term doesn't converge to $0$.